# Remove option from select where text started with 'aa'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have select with options:

```
<select id="sel">
    <option value="1">aadkdo</option>    
    <option value="2">sdsdf</option>
    <option value="3">aasdfsddkdo</option>
    <option value="4">aadkfsdfdo</option>
    <option value="5">sdfs</option>
    <option value="6">aafsdfdkdo</option>
    <option value="7">sdfsdf</option>
</select>
```

How can i remove from this select all option where text started with **aa**. For my example thera are 1, 3, 4 and 6.

```
$('#sel option').each(function(){
    if(???){
       $(this).remove();   
    }
})
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AzXEW/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this;

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Allendar/AzXEW/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#sel option').each(function(){
        if ($(this).html().substring(0, 2) == 'aa'){
           $(this).remove();   
        }
    })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#sel option').filter(function(){return $(this).text().indexOf("aa") === 0; }).remove();
```

Comment: No problem, also `this` won't have a `text()` method, needs to be `$(this)` (unless you've defined your own method/extended the prototype, etc).

Answer (score 1):

you can use regexp.

```
if($(this).val().match("^aa"))
```